# The study of Mathematical Visualization , Where Do I start?

Tags: computer-science

I've looked through the literature on this topic , but it seems way to complex for me. 
I need some help , would you guide me through the process , from beginning to end.

Comment: "would you guide me through the process , from beginning to end." Definitely the forum will if posted in the form of small questions (NOT discussions) in a polite language.

Comment: What you mean? Mathematical visualization of what - specifically?

Answer (score 1):

At first you may take a look at Proof without words, it's just the general definition for expressing mathematical statement by diagrams and pictures, start from [Proof without words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_without_words)
.

There are great book in the field of two parts [Proofs without Words: Exercises in Visual Thinking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857006) and [Proofs Without Words II: More Exercises in Visual Thinking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857219), it's good for training your motivation in general in many fields of mathematics, at least it's worth taking a look at the beginning.

After that you can proceed with textbook in fields you are interested in, for example if you interested in computer science you may want to take a look at [Mathematical Visualization: Algorithms, Applications and Numerics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642083730).

From my personal experience, if you interested in mathematical visualization it's worth having any other fundamental textbook in the field at hands, just in case if you want going further into details.